# How to do linear interpolation?

Tags: math, distance, linear-interpolation

I have line segment with start s(x1,y1) and end e(x2,y2). I have calculated distance between s and e by using euclidean distance 
    d = sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2))
How to find out point on the line segment at distance d1 (0 < d1< d)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main theme of linearity is that *everything is proportional*.

`d1` is `d1/d` fraction of the way from `0` to `d`.

Therefore, the point, `p`, that you are looking for is the same fraction of
the way from `s` to `e`. So let `r = d1/d`. Then

```
p = (x1 + r*(x2-x1), y1 + r*(y2-y1))
```

Notice that when `r` equals 0, `p` is `(x1 + 0*(x2-x1), y1 + 0*(y2-y1)) = (x1, y1) = s`. And when `r` equals 1, `p` is `e = (x2, y2)`. As `r` goes from `0` to `1`, `p` goes from `s` to `t` linearly -- that is, as a linear function of `r`.

Answer (score 0):

**parametric Line** is defined like this:

```
x(t)=x1+(x2-x1)*t;
y(t)=y1+(y2-y1)*t;
```

- where `t` is parameter in range `<0.0,1.0>`
- if `t=0.0` then the result is giving  point (x1,y1)
- if `t=1.0` then the result is giving  point (x2,y2)

So if you need point at d distance from start then:

```
D=sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
x(d)=x1+(x2-x1)*d/D;
y(d)=y1+(y2-y1)*d/D;
```

- where `D` is line length
- and `d` is distance from start point